# if form.validate_on_submit() works for one route but not the other Flask-WTF

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

So, I'm bulding forms to add data to a database.
I started with a /addRecepie route and it works just fine.
When I submit the form its validated and runs the code.

```
@app.route("/addRecepie", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addRecepie():
    form = AddRecepie()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Validated")
        recepie = Recepie(recepie=form.recepie_name.data, recepie_description=form.recepie_description.data)
        db.session.add(recepie)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Det gick bra','success')
        return redirect(url_for('addRecepie'))
    return render_template('addRecepie.html', form=form)
```

Next I did the exact same setup for a /editRecepie route where the only difference is that I use a query parameter to pass an ID.

```
@app.route("/editRecepie/<int:recepie_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editRecepie(recepie_id):
    form = AddIngredientForm()
    print(f'recepie_id1 = {recepie_id}')
    recepie = Recepie.query.get_or_404(recepie_id)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Validated")
    return render_template('editRecepie.html', form=form, recepie=recepie, RecepieSteps=RecepieSteps, RecepieIngredients=RecepieIngredients)
```

The HTML and the forms look exactly the same, except different number of fields and names.

```
class AddRecepie(FlaskForm):
    recepie_name = StringField('Namn', validators=[DataRequired()])
    recepie_description = StringField('Beskrivning', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Skapa')

class AddIngredientForm(FlaskForm):
    ingredient = StringField('Ingrediens', validators=[DataRequired()])
    amount = IntegerField('Mängd', validators=[DataRequired()])
    unit = StringField('Enhet', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Lägg till ingrediens')
```

In the form that works, I got {{ form.hidden_tag() }}. I also tryed using {{ form.csrf_token }} but that made no difference.

When I submit the form, it adds the csrf token in the adress bar.
http://127.0.0.1:5000/editRecepie/1?csrf_token=IjAxYmE3YzQ1Y2ZmNTkzYWY2YmQyMTZkN2UxODhiZmVmNjZjZTY5Nzki.ZMgVmw.M_UZI06I-hYg4WA_isEwjvqOR9Y&csrf_token=IjAxYmE3YzQ1Y2ZmNTkzYWY2YmQyMTZkN2UxODhiZmVmNjZjZTY5Nzki.ZMgVmw.M_UZI06I-hYg4WA_isEwjvqOR9Y&ingredient=dasda&amount=1&unit=st&submit=L%C3%A4gg+till+ingrediens.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Im trying to submit a form and expect if form.validate_on_submit() to work.

Comment: It seems that GET is selected as the request type instead of POST, because in a GET request the data is sent as a URL parameter. Check the `method` attribute of your `form` tag.

Comment: sigh* a simple typo in method...I missed it over and over again. Its working now, thanks!